# Troubles with events in fragments transactions

Tags: android, android-fragments

Im developing an app and on my first activity, I'm using an tablayout and a viewpager. So when the user, change the tabs the fragment change too. But the problem is on the second tab. In that tab I use a "container" so, when the user change to this tab, I add a fragmentOne and it has a button, when I click on that button, I replace the fragment whit a fragmentTwo. Now, on this second fragment I have a textview, when I click in that textview I want to change to the firstFragment. The trouble I think is because both have an onActivityCreated and the belong to the same activity. This is my code.

Containerfragment:

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    RegistroUnoFragment registroUnoFragment = new RegistroUnoFragment();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =  getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.contenedorRegistro, registroUnoFragment).commit();
}
```

This is my first fragment:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    btnContinuar = (Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.btnContinuar);

    btnContinuar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RegistroDosFragment registroDosFragment = new RegistroDosFragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.contenedorRegistro, registroDosFragment).commit();
        }
    });

}
```

and in this fragment is when I want to return my first fragment

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    tviRetroceder = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.tviRetroceder);
    tviRetroceder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RegistroUnoFragment registroUnoFragment = new RegistroUnoFragment();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.contenedorRegistro, registroUnoFragment).commit();
        }
}
```

Comment: set a listener over text view as well and do replacement work inside it.

Comment: sorry, I forget to put that code. But I alredy do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tviRetroceder` `OnClickListener` creates a new `RegsitroUnoFragment` called `registroUnoFragment`. But there is **already** a `RegistroUnoFragment` in existence called `registroUnoFragment` created in your container activity in its onCreate method. You cannot create it again.  You have to "find" this fragment and only then add it to the container. So you need to check if the gragment is NULL first.

Use "replace" and not "add" and use a tag so that you can find the fragment e.g.

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.contenedorRegistro,registroUnoFragment,"TagUno");
```

Then in the OnClick

```
RegistroUnoFragment registroUnoFragment=(RegistroUnoFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag("TagUno");

if(registroUnoFragment!=null) {
{fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.contenedorRegistro,registroUnoFragment,"TagUno");
}
```